# How to install GNU on FreeBsd 10?

Tags: freebsd

i have error

```
configure: error: GNU make is required!
```

and i have error

```
$ cd /usr/ports/devel/gmake/
cd: /usr/ports/devel/gmake/: No such file or directory
```

How to install GNU on FreeBsd 10?

Answer (score 1):

`pkg install gmake`

also, you have to install the ports tree if you want to be able to install ports from source.